# How to show $n! = \omega\big((\frac{n}{3})^{n+e}\big)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm learning some mathematics by myself and get stuck. The problem is to show that

$n! = \omega\big((\frac{n}{3})^{n+e}\big)$, $\omega$ is the asymptotic notation.

It's from the Problem Set 7 of [MIT 6.042](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/)

Comment: Just to clarify myself on the little $\omega$ notation: $f \in \omega(g) \iff g \in o(f)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use stirling approximation

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\log(n!) & = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k) = \int_{1^-}^{n^+} \log(t) d \lfloor t \rfloor = \log(n) n - \int_{1^-}^{n^+} \dfrac{\lfloor t \rfloor}t dt\\
& = \log(n) n - \int_{1^-}^{n^+} \dfrac{t - \{t \}}t dt = \log(n) n - n + \underbrace{\int_{1^-}^{n^+} \dfrac{\{t \}}t dt}_{> 0}\\
& > n \log n - n = \log \left(\dfrac{n^n}{e^n}\right)
\end{align}
Hence, we get that $n! > \left(\dfrac{n}e \right)^n$. Now prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{n}3\right)^{n+e}}{\left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^n} = 0 $$ and then you are done.

> But, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{n}3\right)^{n+e}}{\left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n/3)^e}{(3/e)^n} = 0$$Hence, $\left(\dfrac{n}3\right)^{n+e} \in o \left( \left(\dfrac{n}e\right)^n\right) \in o \left(\mathcal{O} \left( n!\right) \right) = o \left( n!\right)$

Comment: What does $d \lfloor t\rfloor $,$\{t\}$ mean ?

Comment: @Belgi $\lfloor t \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function also called the floor of $t$. $\{t\}$ is the fractional part of $t$ i.e. $\{t\} = t - \lfloor t \rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't understand the meaning of it (in the first integral) instead of $dt$

Comment: @Belgi The integral I have written is nothing but a fancy way of Abel summation formula, which you may want to look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula). The integral is to be interprested as a Riemann Stieltjes integral.  You may want to look at this question for more detials. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154420/eulers-summation-by-parts-formula