# Hint on a limit that involves the Hurwitz Zeta function

Tags: limits, zeta-functions

I will be honest. Some play with a weird integral has gotten me to this formulation:
$$\lim\limits_{n\mathop\to\infty}\frac{\zeta(2,n)}{\frac 1n+\frac 1{2n^2}}=1$$
It seems true because of the numerical approximations made and the actual evaluation of this limit at Wolfram Alpha. But i am stuck. Does anyone have an idea of where to start?

Comment: Of course i will!

Comment: The idea is correct. I made a correction. The limit should be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that:
$$\zeta(2,n)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,e^{-nt}}{1-e^{-t}}\,dt$$
but since the integral on $[\pi,+\infty)$ is very small (exponentially small in $n$) we can just consider the Taylor series of $\frac{t}{1-e^{-t}}$ with respect to the point $t=0$ in order to have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\zeta(2,n)&=&\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(1+\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{12}+O(t^4)\right)e^{-nt}\,dt + O(e^{-n})\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{12}\right)e^{-nt}\,dt+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{6n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right),\end{eqnarray*}$$
that is much stronger than the limit it is asked to prove.

Answer (score 3):

If $\zeta(2,n)$ gives the generalized Riemann zeta function, for large values of $n$, the Taylor expansion is $$\zeta(2,n)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{6 n^3}-\frac{1}{30
   n^5}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^7\right)$$ So,$$\frac{\zeta(2,n)}{\frac 1n+\frac 1{2n^2}}=1+\frac{1}{6 n^2}-\frac{1}{12 n^3}+\frac{1}{120 n^4}-\frac{1}{240 n^5}+\frac{29}{1120
   n^6}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^7\right)$$ and then $$\lim\limits_{n\mathop\to\infty}\frac{\zeta(2,n)}{\frac 1n+\frac 1{2n^2}}=1$$

Comment: Just to be a major nitpicker: how do you prove that $\zeta(2,n)$ has such Taylor series?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio apply [Watson's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) to the integral representation of $\zeta(2,n)$ appeared in your answer?

Comment: @achillehui: yes, for sure ;) I was just debating answers like "in virtue of the following unproven relation, your limit equals..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asymptotic expansion of $\zeta(2,n)$

> $$ \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{2}{2n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3}) .$$

See [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361386/is-there-a-formula-for-sum-n-1k-frac1n3/361511#361511).

**Added:** I provided my answer based on your request for a hint. However here is [one technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246386/finding-asymptotes-of-exponential-function-and-one-sided-limit) you can use.

Comment: Just to be a major nitpicker: how do you prove this identity?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The OP asked for a hint! However you can find some techniques that I used in different answers if you are interested. So the main idea for solving the problem was given in this answer.

Comment: you just posted a shortened version of C.Leibovici's answer, what is the point in writing it? The OP already had such a hint in a previously posted answer.