# General formula for the sum of x raised to general degree: $(1^z + 2^z + \cdots+ x^z)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation, summation-method

As I was reading a book on the financial market micro-structure, I came across a simplification that I have not been able to prove.

The book states that $\sum_{\ell=1}^{Q}2G_0(\frac{1+\gamma}{\ell})\ell^\delta \approx 2G_0(1+\gamma)\frac{Q^\delta}{\delta}, \text{where } Q >> 1$ and $0<\delta<1$.

The first simplification is obvious: $\sum_{\ell=1}^{Q}2G_0(\frac{1+\gamma}{\ell})\ell^\delta = 2G_0(1+\gamma)\sum_{\ell=1}^{Q}\ell^{\delta-1}$.

I am not sure how $\sum_{\ell=1}^{Q}\ell^{\delta-1} \approx \frac{Q^\delta}{\delta}, \text{for where Q >> 1 and } 0<\delta<1$.

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) will do when $z$ is an integer $\ge0$.

Comment: Alternatively, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) might prove enlightening.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks!! z is not an integer unfortunately. I should have bee clearer. Any suggestions given that z is not an integer?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Are you suggesting evaluating the sum using an integration? $\int_{\ell=1}^{Q} \ell ^ {\delta-1}$ will result in $\approx \frac{Q^\delta}{\delta}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{\ell=1}^{Q}\ell^{\delta-1}=H_Q^{(1-\delta )}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers.

For large values of $Q$, we have
$$H_Q^{(1-\delta )}=Q^{\delta -1} \left(\frac{Q}{\delta }+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\delta -1}{12
   Q}+O\left(\frac{1}{Q^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (1-\delta )$$

Comment: Thank you @Claude. Where did you get the formula for $H_Q^{1-\delta}$ for large values of Q from?

Comment: @vpy. Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583452/assymptotics-of-the-generalized-harmonic-number-h-n-r-for-r-1