# Where does $s-1$ come from in this $\zeta(s)$ equation?

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

I have been working my way through [this Arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02301.pdf) concerning the analytic continuation of the zeta function.  I don't understand the first equality in equation (19), page 6.

In equation (11), the paper gives the definition

$$\eta(s):=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

Equation (14) summarises results so far as

$$\zeta (s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}=\frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}}=\frac{1}{s-1}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n}{(n+1)^s}-\frac{n-s}{n^s}\right)$$

which is fine. But equation (19) then asserts that

$$\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\zeta(s)=\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\frac{s-1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1}n^{-s}$$

Doubtless I'm being unobservant / stupid - but where does the factor $s-1$ come in? In equation (14) we have $\zeta (s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$ - and now in equation (19) we have $\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\zeta(s)=\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\frac{s-1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$...

How and why does the extra factor $s-1$ appear? Presumably it's something to do with the limit-taking process, but I don't understand.

Comment: $\lim_{s\to 1}\zeta(s)=\lim_{s\to 1}\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n+1}n^{-s}=\infty$ there is no $s-1$.

Comment: You are right, it seems they mean $\lim_{s\to 1}(s-1)\zeta(s)=1$? See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412616/showing-that-displaystyle-lim-s-to1s-1-zetas-1). Perhaps you should read a classical book on the subject, which you can trust. For example, Riemann's Zeta Function by Harold Edwards.

Comment: Thank you both.